# Does Kotlin has a keyword `None`, like Python?

Tags: kotlin, keyword

I use python almost everyday. Now I am learning Kotlin. I wonder if there is `None` in Kotlin so that we can do something like:

```py
v1 = None
if v1 is None:
    pass
    # then we do something
```

I did some research, and I found there is `none` in `kotlin-stdlib/kotlin.collection`, but that does not seems to be something I am looking for.

If there is such keyword like None in Kotlin, how can it be used? If not, how does Kotlin deal with the situation like the code shown above?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Kotlin's equivalent to Python's `None` is `null`.

Note that Kotlin has something called ["null safety"](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html), so any variables that can receive `null` must be declared as nullable.

Comment: More comprehensive link : https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/kotlin-for-py/null-safety.html

Answer (score 1):

`null` is the alternative for 'None` (Python) in Kotlin

Answer (score 0):

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html

use the keyword "null" instead. in the documentation there is some examples how to use it. It is slightly different than using None in python but it is not complex if you know some C# I think because it has also this same null safety typing feature